# Show that simple and connected graph is forest if and only if every edge is cut edge

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple and connected graph $G=(V,E)$, how can we show that *$G$* is a forest if and only if  every edge is a cut edge?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you do one of the two directions?

Comment: Do try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: It's probably easier to prove the logically equivalent theorem:

> Theorem: $G$ has a cycle if and only if there exists an edge that is not a cut edge.